# Como usar 'while' em uma 'isNaN()'?

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

Eu estou fazendo um teste de "questionário" e para funcionar o usuário tem que digitar apenas números, caso não digite, será emitido uma mensagem de erro para ele repetir o processo.

Consegui resolver isso com o seguinte:

```
if (isNaN(variavel1)) 
{
    Variavel1 = Prompt("Só são permitido numeros, tente novamente ");
}
```

Mas o problema é que isso só funciona uma vez. Se o usuário na segunda tentativa continuar escrevendo letras, o programa não manda ele digitar novamente.

Tentei usar o `while` mas não estou sabendo como usar para esse caso especifico.
Se puderem me ajudar, agradeço.

Comment: Por que nao validar com HTML5? Só colocar input type number e pronto....

Comment: Sim, mas esqueci de informar, estou aprendendo Javascript. Por isso

Answer (score 6, accepted):

É possível validar no evento `keyup`... mas não recomendo mostrar um popup e sim algo mais sutil como alterar a cor do texto. Veja o exemplo:

```js
var tb = document.getElementById("num");
tb.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
  tb.className = isNaN(tb.value) ? "invalid" : "valid";
});
```

```css
.invalid {
  color: red;
  }
```

```html
<input id="num" type="textbox" />
```